# How to collect user profile page views and button clicks?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a web app where I want to show app users analytics for their public profile pages. Namely, page views and button clicks.

I am new to Google Analytics (GA) and user activity tracking in general. I have spent some time reading through guides and pricing for GA, but I find their documentation confusing. Does anyone know what the best approach for using GA is to accomplish my desired goal?